# Transaction not starting in Oracle 12c in some cases

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

We have recently moved from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12c. The webapp we are using works on Hibernate. So, when a transaction is begun on some thread, then some times it runs and sometimes it gives following error. This error was not coming earlier when we were working on 11g but is coming in 12c. Is there anything we need to change in code as per Oracle12c? We have already using new ojdbc driver for oracle 12c. Please help us out.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1224)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
        at com.xyz.geo.wherehaus.ui.data.ImportTask.startTransaction(ImportTask.java:243)
        at com.xyz.geo.wherehaus.ui.data.ImportTask.call(ImportTask.java:105)
        at com.xyz.geo.wherehaus.ui.data.ImportTask.call(ImportTask.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin failed:
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:4337)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:125)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer.invoke(ResetAbandonedTimer.java:63)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
```

Comment: What is your `DB version` up to four decimals? Is it a `PDB` or `CDB`? Did you check `MOS`?

Comment: It is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release  12.1.0.1.0

Comment: That is just one part of the answer, I asked you more details.

Comment: Actually I dont know what are PDB and CDB and MOS? And how to check them. Can you help?

Comment: PDB - Pluggable databases, CDB - Container databases and MOS - My Oracle Support. Anyway, looking at the log you posted, the issue seems to be with the `JDBC connection` and Oracle is just the victim. Culprit seems to be the `connection method`.

Comment: Seems like it's a stale database connection issue. Perhaps, connection terminated by server, but the pool thinks it to be up. Try configuring connection test in the connection pool configuration.

Comment: As I have have mentioned above, that it is working sometimes and sometimes it is giving above error. So, it is quite inconsistent. I have also tried with different ojdbc drivers

Comment: That is whyI asked you to search `MOS`.